# Firebase - Cannot resolve symbol 'MyFirebaseMessagingService'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to push notification on my apps from Google Firebase. However in my AndroidManifest.xml file, the problem seems to be at

```
      <service
        android:name=".MapsActivity">
```

I'm getting error because of the same name appear on

```
    <activity
    android:name=".MapsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

From the tutorial, it supposed to be like

```
android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
```

but i'm changing it because in my MainActivity.java class is

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
         android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MapsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MapsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If you using device to testing your app, say me their model please

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez sony xperia z2

Comment: Ok, can you show me your dependencies (build and app)?

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez just edited my post with build.gradle

Comment: Maps activity is an **Activity**, not a `Service` class, so why are you confused?

Comment: Also, I think you can put two `intent-filter` within one service tag of the manifest

Comment: you need to create a class that extends the `FirebaseMessagingService` then you can put your it in the service tag

Comment: You can see the whole code here, for reference. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm

Comment: I created a class that extends FirebaseMessagingService according to coding in the github but still it doesn't work. And I had changed the androidmanifest.xml to android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">

Answer (score 1):

This part of code is the problem:

```
<service
    android:name=".MapsActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".MapsActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**Why?** The service can't be an activity and can't have the same name. The both services extends of different services then you need one class to extends the first service and other one to extends the second service, as in the example:

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService:**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
     ...
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
     ...
}
```

Then your **manifest** will looks like as:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

For the other part remember that, you have 2 gradles (app and project). Too see the both, in project part needs to select **project view**.

**app.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And **project.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Let me know if I have helped you and good programming!